# Error when installing serverless on Linuxmint 20.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, serverless

I want to install serverless as global.
`npm install -g serverless`

but when the installation process, I got the same error like this

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules/serverless/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...","querystring":"^0.2'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/fathisiddiqi/.npm/_logs/2020-09-17T07_24_40_981Z-debug.log
```

I have clean npm cache with `npm cache clean --force`
I tried again, and got another errors like this

```
npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash (over 30000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/fathisiddiqi/.npm/_logs/2020-09-17T07_26_46_746Z-debug.log
```

Finally, i tried to install serverless again. but still got message

```
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...TTOgEjCFo9YXvGwfWu94f'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/fathisiddiqi/.npm/_logs/2020-09-17T07_30_56_320Z-debug.log
```

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: what version of npm you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first

```
npm cache clean --force
```

second

To update to a new major version all the packages, install the npm-check-updates package globally:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

then run it:

```
ncu -u
```

This will upgrade all the version hints in the package.json file, to dependencies and devDependencies, so npm can install the new major version.

You are now ready to run the update:

```
npm update
```

then `install your package`

Comment: I just clean cache and uninstall these package first after that reinstall again.

Comment: did my method work for you?if it was helpful accept it as your solution so that it may help others in future :)

Answer (score 0):

please uninstall your global serverless and clear cache

`npm uninstall -g serverless`

and

`npm cache clear --force`